# Select rows which contain numeric substrings in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to delete rows from a dataframe in which a particular column contains string which contains numeric substrings. See the shaded column of my dataframe.

[image]

rows with values like 0E as prefix or 21 (any two digit number) as suffix or 24A (any two digit number with a letter) as suffix should be deleted.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing with a [**`str.contains()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) regex:

- `^0E` - starts with `0E`
- `\d{2}$` - ends with 2 digits
- `\d{2}[A-Z]$` - ends with 2 digits and 1 capital letter

```py
col = ... # target column
mask = df[col].str.contains(r'^0E|\d{2}$|\d{2}[A-Z]$')
df = df.loc[~mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

@tdy gave a good answer, but only one place need to be modified if I understand it correctly.

For value ends with two digits or two digits and a capital character, the regex should be:

- `.*\d{2}[A-Z]?$`

Comment: good catch +1, thanks! updated (though these generally belong in comments)

Comment: @tdy no worries, saw your answer when I was still editing. :)

Comment: actually just noticed you combined the last two regexes as well, nice!

Comment: I figured it out from his answer and corrected in the code.. it worked very well. thanks to all.